# getting the structure name with boost fusion

Tags: c++, templates, boost, boost-fusion

Using `boost::fusion` is possible to iterate an adapted structure and get the name of each member of that structure.

Is there a way to retrieve also the name of the structure some way?

What I woulld like to do is the following: given the current scenario

```
namespace inner { 
struct test_struct {
  int a;
  int b;
} }

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT( inner::test_struct, a, b );
```

I'd like to have a function that will return "test_struct" (or "inner::test_struct" )

I did check the header file[*] containing `struct_size` and other extension classes but I haven't found any with that purpose.

Do you know if there is anything out there to do that?

[*] boost/fusion/adapted/struct/detail/extension.hpp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a feature. You can see it by inspecting the output of the preprocessor.

You can see the `struct_member_name` extension, but no such literals for the struct name:

```
namespace boost {
    namespace fusion {
        namespace traits {
            template <> struct tag_of<inner::test_struct> { typedef struct_tag type; };
            template <> struct tag_of<inner::test_struct const> {
                typedef struct_tag type;
            };
        } // namespace traits
        namespace extension {
            template <> struct access::struct_member<inner::test_struct, 0> {
                struct deduced_attr_type {
                    static const inner::test_struct& obj;
                    typedef boost::type_of::remove_cv_ref_t<decltype(obj.a)> type;
                };
                typedef deduced_attr_type::type attribute_type;
                typedef attribute_type type;
                template <typename Seq> struct apply {
                    typedef typename add_reference<
                        typename mpl::eval_if<is_const<Seq>, add_const<attribute_type>,
                                 mpl::identity<attribute_type>>::type>::type
                                     type;
                    constexpr static type call(Seq& seq) { return seq.a; }
                };
            };
            template <> struct struct_member_name<inner::test_struct, 0> {
                typedef char const* type;
                constexpr static type call() { return "a"; }
            };
            template <> struct access::struct_member<inner::test_struct, 1> {
                struct deduced_attr_type {
                    static const inner::test_struct& obj;
                    typedef boost::type_of::remove_cv_ref_t<decltype(obj.b)> type;
                };
                typedef deduced_attr_type::type attribute_type;
                typedef attribute_type type;
                template <typename Seq> struct apply {
                    typedef typename add_reference<
                        typename mpl::eval_if<is_const<Seq>, add_const<attribute_type>,
                                 mpl::identity<attribute_type>>::type>::type
                                     type;
                    constexpr static type call(Seq& seq) { return seq.b; }
                };
            };
            template <> struct struct_member_name<inner::test_struct, 1> {
                typedef char const* type;
                constexpr static type call() { return "b"; }
            };
            template <> struct struct_size<inner::test_struct> : mpl::int_<2> {};
            template <> struct struct_is_view<inner::test_struct> : mpl::false_ {};
        } // namespace extension
    } // namespace fusion
    namespace mpl {
        template <typename> struct sequence_tag;
        template <> struct sequence_tag<inner::test_struct> {
            typedef fusion::fusion_sequence_tag type;
        };
        template <> struct sequence_tag<inner::test_struct const> {
            typedef fusion::fusion_sequence_tag type;
        };
    } // namespace mpl
} // namespace boost
```

As always, it may not be too hard to add your own macro to get the extra information. See e.g. [Parsing Selector struct with alternating tokens using Boost Spirit X3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61315488/parsing-selector-struct-with-alternating-tokens-using-boost-spirit-x3/61325740#61325740) or [Boost fusion sequence type and name identification for structs and class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26380420/boost-fusion-sequence-type-and-name-identification-for-structs-and-class/26381145#26381145)

Comment: Hi Sehe. Thanks for pointing me to the internal of the code. I'll wrap it as you suggest.